# Joining two tables and return all records which appear in either table

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables, one which contains parts costs and another which contains labour costs.

I would like to join these tables to show all the labour and parts costs but there are some records in the `Part Costs` table which do not exist in the `Labour Costs` table and vice versa.

#### Parts Costs Table

```
Call Ref    Serial Number   Parts Costs
1111        AB66            12
2222        AC66            100
3333        AD66            200
4444        AE66            55
5555        AF66            54
```

#### Labour Costs Table

```
Call Ref    Serial Number   Labour Costs
8888        AG66            200
1111        AB66            300
2222        AC66            400
9999        AH66            500
```

The result I am trying to achieve is:

```
Call Ref    Serial Number   Parts Costs Labour Costs
1111        AB66            12          300
2222        AC66            100         400
3333        AD66            200         0
4444        AE66            55          0
5555        AF66            54          0
8888        AG66            0           200
9999        AH66            0           500
```

Comment: google "sql join tutorial"...plenty of hits...

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Please show us what you have attempted so far, and also add a tag for the RDBMS that you are using (MSSQL, MySql, etc).

Comment: Not sure why all of the "close" requests, since the user very clearly defined the expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a FULL OUTER JOIN.

For example:

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(LC.call_ref, PC.call_ref) AS call_ref,
    COALESCE(LC.serial_number], PC.serial_number) AS serial_number,
    LC.cost AS labour_costs,
    PC.cost AS parts_costs
FROM
    Labour_Costs LC
FULL OUTER JOIN Parts_Costs PC ON
    PC.call_ref = LC.call_ref AND
    PC.serial_number = LC.serial_number
```

You should probably consider getting rid of the spaces in your table/column names in the database. Some 3rd party products won't work well with them and they can make coding a hassle since you need to always use the brackets for your object names (also making the code less readable, IMO).

Also, this code doesn't take into account the possibility of multiple rows appearing in one of the tables for the same ref/serial number. If that's a possibility then you'll need to `SUM` the costs and add a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Square brackets for identifier are illegal in (standard) SQL. To quote identifiers with invalid characters you need to use double quotes in SQL, e.g. `"Serial Number"` (and the question is only tagged `sql` currently, not `sql-server` or `tsql`)

Comment: I didn't say that it doesn't conform to standard SQL. Just because it conforms to the standard doesn't make it a good idea though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your join key is Call Ref + Serial Number.

In MS SQL Server you can achieve the above by using a full join:

```
SELECT CallRef       = ISNULL(pc.CallRef, lc.CallRef),
       SerialNumber  = ISNULL(pc.SerialNumber, lc.SerialNumber),
       PartCost      = ISNULL(pc.PartCost, 0),
       LaborCost     = ISNULL(lc.LaborCost, 0)
FROM   PartCost pc
FULL JOIN LaborCost lc ON pc.CallRef = lc.CallRef AND pc.SerialNumber = lc.SerialNumber
```

Comment: Answers to questions tagged `sql` should use standard SQL.